# c# Keep getting index is out of bounds when using "array[x].contains(array2[y]"

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been banging my head on this for a while.  I keep getting Index out of Bounds when running this code..

basically,  I took a textbox,  split it up into an array, then using each index of the array to compare to a array full of strings.  Pasted relevant code,  can you guys see what I did wrong?

I've set put an error near the point of error.   ( <----- )

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    string[] kbsubject = new string[4000];
    string[] kbbody = new string[4000];
    string[] wordsplit = new string[4000];
    int[] hits = new int[4000];
     StreamWriter WriteBody = new StreamWriter("kbsubjecttest.txt");
    StreamReader readSubject = new StreamReader("kbsubject.txt");
    StreamReader readBody = new StreamReader("kbbody.txt");
    int IndexHolder = 0, counter = 0, counterSearch = 0, WordsIndex = 0, counterWord=0, ArrayIndex = 0;
    string compareBody, compareSubject;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();




    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        wordsplit = SearchBox.Text.Split(' ');
        diagWindow.Items.Add(wordsplit.Length);
        diagWindow.Items.Add("Preforming search by split");
        WordsIndex = 1;
        counterWord = 1;
        while (counterSearch != wordsplit.Length)
        {
            if (kbbody[counterWord].Contains(wordsplit[WordsIndex]))   <--------
            {
                hits[ArrayIndex] = counterWord;
                ArrayIndex++;
                counterWord++;
                WordsIndex++;




            }
            else
            {
                ArrayIndex++;
                counterWord++;
                WordsIndex++;
            }

        }



        }
```

Comment: Where are you even using counterSearch ? Seems you would just keep going until countersearch equals wordsplit.length, but you're never incrementing it or doing anything with it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

**This line is your bug:**
`WordsIndex = 1;` // I think the issue it quiet simple, why it's starting from 1? **it should be zero**.

counterWord should start from 0 as well, and you should stop iterating when:
`counterSearch < wordsplit.Length` **and not** `counterSearch != wordsplit.Length`

If this code is written in both `if` and `else` it should moved to after both scopes:

```
ArrayIndex++;
counterWord++;
WordsIndex++;
```

**Fixed code:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    string[] kbsubject = new string[4000];
    string[] kbbody = new string[4000];
    string[] wordsplit = new string[4000];
    int[] hits = new int[4000];
     StreamWriter WriteBody = new StreamWriter("kbsubjecttest.txt");
    StreamReader readSubject = new StreamReader("kbsubject.txt");
    StreamReader readBody = new StreamReader("kbbody.txt");
    int IndexHolder = 0, counter = 0, counterSearch = 0, WordsIndex = 0, counterWord=0, ArrayIndex = 0;
    string compareBody, compareSubject;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        wordsplit = SearchBox.Text.Split(' ');
        diagWindow.Items.Add(wordsplit.Length);
        diagWindow.Items.Add("Preforming search by split");
        WordsIndex = 0;
        counterWord = 0;
        while (counterSearch < wordsplit.Length)
        {
            if (kbbody[counterWord].Contains(wordsplit[WordsIndex]))   <--------
            {
                hits[ArrayIndex] = counterWord;
            }

            ArrayIndex++;
            counterWord++;
            WordsIndex++;                
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
while (counterSearch != wordsplit.Length)
```

You don't change the value of neither `counterSearch` nor `wordsplit` so the loop is running indefinitely, finally causing index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting WordsIndex and/or CounterWord to 0 instead of 1 before starting the while loop. It is possibly the cause of the IndexOutOfBounds error, because arrays are zero-indexed.